# How to let a user add and remove items to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks a button, it pops up a `dialog` with an `EditText` and an *OK* `Button`. When the user completes, the dialog, it should *add* the item they just typed in to the `ListView`. How do I do this?

I will need a large code example; this is my first application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to follow the official notepad tutorial example. It's very comprehensive. It does 95% of what you want to do.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: I can't figure out how to take that and put be able to use the things it shows in my app.

Comment: I know I will need an SQLite database. I want the least amount of extra stuff as possible.

Comment: Go through this tutorial step-by-step, and tell me exactly where you get stuck. It will take you time to go through it all, but this needs to be done. In terms of code, this tutorial contains no fluff at all (though, I'll admit it's wordy as hell in terms of explanations). You'll need a DB adapter, there is really no going around that. First do the tutorial, then worry about creating a database with your text already in there.

Comment: I would like only one .java file, but I guess I'll need two.

Comment: I'm halfway through, and I understand it, but I don't see how I can take what it's doing and put it into my app. I'll finish it and try, but I'll need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a sample code. There is a button to add text in list and long press on list item will remove it.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Add Item" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:inputType="text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="CANCEL" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.listexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemLongClickListener {

    private ArrayList<String> datasource;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        datasource = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel).setOnClickListener(
                        MainActivity.this);
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_ok).setOnClickListener(
                        MainActivity.this);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return datasource.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return datasource.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) convertView;
            if (null == view) {
                view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                view.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            }
            view.setText(datasource.get(position));
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_cancel:
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.button_ok:
            String text = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_box))
                    .getText().toString();
            if (null != text && 0 != text.compareTo("")) {
                datasource.add(text);
                dialog.dismiss();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
            int position, long column) {
        datasource.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning for this line of code?
"view = new TextView(MainActivity.this);"
I mean,... what if we don't put that as the parameter for the view?
I just doesn't understand that part....

Comment: Each UI widget requires Activity context. "MainActivity.this" is the context to which this text view would be bound to. I think context is a mandatory parameter. We can not avoid it.